# Why is nativeElement of elementRef undefined?

Tags: javascript, html, angular

```
<div class="parent">
            <div class="input-group">
            <input  [(ngModel)]="InputValue" 
              #Field (input)="changedEvent()" (focus)="onFocus()" />
            <button (click)="changedEvent()">click</button>
            </div>
    
            <div #Container *ngIf="isFocused">
              // a table
            </div>

</div>
```

Having the above code I try to access the nativeElement of the elementRefs #Field and #Container in the changedEvent() method as follows :

```
  //this is how they have been declared in the component
  @ViewChild('Container', { static: false }) Container: ElementRef;
  @ViewChild('Field', { static: false }) Field: ElementRef;

  //inside the method
  const element = this.Field.nativeElement;
  const list = this.Container.nativeElement;
```

When go to this method, when the input listener of the text field is triggered it works fine. However when click the button and go here the Container ElementRef is undefined. (Field is defined).
Would like to know what I am missing where it works from the input listener but not when directed from the click listener.

Comment: Are you sure `isFocused` is true when the `this.Container.nativeElement` statement is executed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's seems that the Container element is not rendered because of the *ngIf and Angular can't reference it since is not rendered yet. Try to use `[hidden]="!isFocused"` if you don't want the element to be visible but you want the reference to be valid.